# Energy loss of Earth

Tags: earth, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

How does the Earth lose the energy that it gains from the sun's radiation if it is surrounded by - and in contact with - nothing?

Comment: If Earth is not in contact with anything, how can it receive sunlight.

Comment: Probably because there's not "nothing" around earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matter above absolute zero will radiate (electromagnetic) energy no matter what.  This is due to the motion of atoms (specifically charged subatomic particles) in the energized matter.  Conduction between two bodies in thermal contact is only one means of transferring energy - it is different than radiation.  The earth does not need to be in contact with anything to radiate energy.

Answer (score 1):

The Earth radiates heat as well as absorbing it from the Sun. At any given time, it does not radiate *exactly* as much heat as it absorbs, since the difference can be accounted for in changes in its internal energy (climate shifts etc.), as well as in sources of heat here on earth (geothermal and manmade energy).